# Cos'è una "lettera di trasmissione"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> «Ha finito, maresciallo?» E nel contempo diede una guardata alla ragazza. 
>          «Sì, signor tenente.» 
>   
>          «E allora batta subito il verbale e glielo faccia firmare... Ah, e compili anche la **lettera di trasmissione**: dobbiamo mandarlo via con la posta di stamattina.» 
>  
>          «Subito, signor tenente.» E con una faccia scura si alzò e andò a sedere davanti a una grossa macchina da scrivere.

Non capisco il significato di "lettera di trasmissione" nel brano precedente. 
Alla voce "trasmissione" del vocabolario Treccani non ho trovato nulla relativo a una lettera, ma una cerca su Google dà parecchi risultati corrispondenti a diversi modelli di lettere. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di questa espressione?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Penso che si riferisca alla ***lettera di accompagnamento*** con la quale il verbale viene trasmesso, ossia inviato per posta, 
  dove in genere si riepilogano i documenti allegati,  a chi sono diretti e qualsiasi altra utile informazione a seconda del contesto.  –Si tratta di un'espressione burocratica.

Cercando su Google si trovano vari esempi di [lettere di trasmissione](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=lettera%20di%20trasmissione%20).

Comment: Si tratta di lettere che accompagnano altri documenti inviati per posta?

Comment: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta?

Comment: non solo elenco dei documenti ma anche contesto che li riguarda e ragione per la spedizione ed altre informazioni utili a chi userà i documenti tipo chi contattare per chiarimenti ecc ecc

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Penso che sia interessante avere una risposta un po' più completa.

Comment: Penso che sia interessante non riferirsi soltanto al contesto del brano, ma dare una spiegazione più generale.